# Lost internet in Azure VNET

Tags: azure, routes, vnet

We ware moving couple of our VMs from one subnet to another via CLI not being sure what we were doing we did something and we lost outgoing internet access on all our VMs within a VNET. Luckily we use VPN to connect to our environment and we have access to our VMs via local IP addresses. But no any old or even new created VM has internet access, unless it has a public ip associated with it.
Our VNG and VMs are in the same VNET. Here is our effective routes and effective security rules on one of the VM. Would someone give me a hint where to look for?
UPDATE: Actually I just realized that there is an internet since when I curl google.com I get the following result `~$> curl google.com <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> <TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY> <H1>301 Moved</H1> The document has moved <A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>. </BODY></HTML>` but the ping doesn't go through. What is it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The route seems normal but the nsg rule has no inbound traffic allowing from the Internet. It is not clear when you said `But no any old or even new created VM has internet access`. If you want the internet In, you need to add an inbound NSG rule to allow the Internet traffic. But May I know how do you check `lost outgoing internet access on all our VMs `? Do you access the VM locally?

Comment: People normally mistake DNS issues with connection issue.  Can you ping yahoo.com using IP? `ping 98.137.246.7`

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I need outgoing internet access not ingoing, all ingoing access from intrenet is dones via an application gateway (WAF).

Comment: It is not a DNS issues since when I ping google.com it is being resolved, but the further response is just hanged and nothing happens. Actually I just realized that there is an internet since when I curl google.com I get the following result
`~$> curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>`
but the ping doesn't go through. What is it?

Comment: Could you check if the VM itself firewall blocking the outbound ICMP? What about if you ping `www.google.com`? or using nslookup, DIG?

Comment: May I know if there is an update on your side?

Comment: There is no active firewall on the server. Really don't know what could be blocking outgoing ICMP packets since we don'e even have NSG setup specifically. Anyways other than outgoing ping everything else works fine. Thank you for following up.